# Use class type in typescript declaration file

Tags: class, typescript, interface, declaration

How can I use a class type in a declaration file in typescript? (TS 1.8)

EXAMPLE:

```
import File = require("./myclass") // class is defined in this file
type MyClass = File.MyClass; // could also use "import" instead of "type"

interface TheInterface
{
    myvar:MyClass;
}
```

This declaration file seems to be invalid because the compiler says it cannot find "TheInterface" when I use it from a ts file.

I need to be able to use a class as an interface property because else the property would have to be an interface as well. This interface, in turn, could not have any class properties, and so on.... (recursive hell)

What I am saying is this: I am forced to either always use interfaces or not use them at all. And I don't like that. At least it does not seem right to me.

I know I can declare interfaces in a normal TS file aswell, but then I would have to import the TS file. I just want global interfaces with class properties.

And I am not talking about declaring a class in a declaration file (which can be done). That is not what I want!

Comment: "it cannot find TheInterface" → maybe because it is not exported?

Comment: nope does not work with export. keep in mind it's a declaration (d.ts) file

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to define a global interface using a class imported from a module.